# Storing values from a file onto a mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql

So I am trying to make this website that takes in the values that are given to it by a text document and pout them into a mySQL database.  The code I am running in my php doesn't give me any syntax errors, but the values aren't added to the database tables.

```
 $upload = new mysqli('localhost', 'uMoviesRoot', $_POST['password1']);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 echo "There as an error.";
 }

 else {
 mysql_select_db("localhost");
 $file= fopen($_FILES['Upload']['tmp_name'], 'r');

 while(! feof($file)){


$line = fgetcsv($file, 999);
if ($line[0] == "movie") {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO movies (movie, year) VALUES ($line[1], $line[2])");    
    $movieCount++;
    $lastMovie = $line[1];

}
```

Just some background, I have created the tables in mySQL (using MySQL workbench) and made a schema named movies.  There are tables named actors(2 columns), directed_by (2 columns), directors(1 column), movies(2 columns), and performed_in (3 columns).  I only put one of these additions in the code just to make it shorter (since all of the ifs do the same thing).

Is this a problem with my PHP code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `mysql_select_db("movies");`, `localhost` is your server address and not the database name.

**UPDATE** (not testet but this should work):

```
$upload = new mysqli('localhost', 'uMoviesRoot', $_POST['password1']);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "There as an error.";
} else {
  mysql_select_db("movies");
  $file= fopen($_FILES['Upload']['tmp_name'], 'r');

  while(! feof($file)){
    $line = fgetcsv($file, 999);
    if ($line[0] == "movie") {
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO movies (movie, year) VALUES ('$line[1]', '$line[2]')");    
      $movieCount++;
      $lastMovie = $line[1];
    }
  }
}
```

You could also output [mysql_error](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mysql-error.php) to see the errors.

If you have values from user input, you should have a look at [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to avoid SQL injection, etc.

Comment: Movies is the name of the schema.  localhost is the name of the connection and the server.

Comment: Right, you use `mysql_select_db` to select the database schema. So this should be `movies` in your case.